# Why my Graph API / cancel outlook meetings call returns always 404 error

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, api, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get all events associated with a user (in order to cancel them). [Here is the API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

I am able through Powershell and Graph API to see a user, and also to sign out this user with the API.
I am using a token got from oauth2 protocol, with grant type client_credentials. I put the permission "Calendars.ReadWrite".

But I only get 404 errors when trying to get the events with :

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/864abe35-a43f-44c3-9d24-ea7d2ce53907/events' -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}
```

This strange thing is that I can get the user array, or revoke his session...
Do this endpoint not working ?

Thank you

EDIT : Answer was that when a user does not have mailboxes, events URL does not exist, and lead to a 404. It works with user having mailbox.

Comment: Try `.../calendar/events` instead of just `.../events` in the URL

Comment: I tried, but it's all the same.

Comment: I don't see any issue here, are you sure you've supplied a correct user ID? Try with the user principal name

Comment: When I just try to "get" the user with the same user ID it works. When I "post" a revokeSignInSessions with this ID it works also. But when trying to get the list of events, it fails with 404 (also with the UPN)

Comment: Do you think if the user doesn't have any meetings, it returns a 404 error ? I imagine it should return an empty array

Comment: I think you're right, that if the user account is disabled or there's no calendar events it will return a 404. Possibly if the user has no license as well

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the full response (with error message etc.).

1. Have you granted admin consent to `Calendars.Write`?
   In the azure portal, go to `Home > App registrations > your app registration` and then click on "API permissions". I don't think this is the issue but better to be safe than not. I would rather expect a 403 Forbidden if this is the problem.
2. Are you sure that the guid of the user is correct? Check if the user with this `Id` exists in your tenant.
3. Has the user a valid licence?
4. Check if the user has a calendar. Use [Get calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
5. Maybe the user has only group calendar(s). If this is the case, you need `Group.Read.All` or `Group.ReadWrite.All`.
6. Try to get oulook meetings from a user where you are sure that he has a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it appeared that the accounts who do not have any exchange mailbox will not result with an empty return, but with an unexisting URL (that's explains the 404).

It works with an account which holds a mailbox.